# Problems with superior menu items

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

On the following site I can't click on the superior menu items: 
http://sax-holz.ch/fenster/trenn-und-heimatschutzfenster/

But only on this single page on my site. Here (http://sax-holz.ch/fenster/hebeschiebetueren/) for example, it is possible without any problems.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an iframe on top of your menu that is blocking it.

Make the iframe a fixed height:

```
.meteor-frame{
height:200px;
}
```